# What is performing better? .Split once or multiple times?

Tags: c#

So, what is better performance-wise?

```
var wholeStr = "Hello, I am\n a Cat.\n You like cats?;

var str1 = wholeStr.Split('\n')[0];
var str2 = wholeStr.Split('\n')[1];
var str3 = wholeStr.Split('\n')[2];
```

or

```
var wholeStr = "Hello, I am\n a Cat.\n You like cats?;
var strArray = wholeStr.Split('\n');
var str1 = strArray [0];
var str2 = strArray [1];
var str3 = strArray [2];
```

I am really not sure, hence the question.

Comment: See [this](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/amp/). But in your case, it's definitely B.

Comment: You are asking whether doing an operation once is faster or not than doing it thrice?

Comment: Which one do you think has to do more work? However, the only *real* way to tell is to measure it (as a release version) because sometimes the people who write the compiler know of faster ways to do some things.

Comment: I thought of memory and so on. When declaring an own array for the split(), I thought it would maybe cost performance than just assigning the values directly this will be done for only 3 variables.

Comment: No research before posting? At the very least you could have tried StopWatch to check which is better

Comment: @Sunil I am not a native speaker and didnt find good results, i am sorry. Also I didnt know about StopWatch before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can know the answer without even testing, since re-calling a method is logically "slower" than calling it once and working with the result (which is the correct use).

Anyway, I wrote a bit of code to give you a technical answer.

```
static void PerformAction(string name, int n, Action action)
{
    // Warm up
    action();

    List<double> times = new List<double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        action();
        times.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: MIN: {1}, AVG: {2}, MAX: {3}", name, times.Min(), times.Average(), times.Max());
}
```

Testing:

```
var wholeStr = "Hello, I am\n a Cat.\n You like cats?";

PerformAction("Multiple splits", 10000, () =>
{
    var str1 = wholeStr.Split('\n')[0];
    var str2 = wholeStr.Split('\n')[1];
    var str3 = wholeStr.Split('\n')[2];
});

PerformAction("Single split", 10000, () =>
{
    var strArray = wholeStr.Split('\n');
    var str1 = strArray[0];
    var str2 = strArray[1];
    var str3 = strArray[2];
});
```

Result:

```
Multiple splits: MIN: 0, AVG: 0,000537730000000083, MAX: 0,3103
Single split: MIN: 0, AVG: 0,000163129999999993, MAX: 0,4506
```

You can see the difference thanks to the AVG results.

Comment: You've not put the code for PerformAction

Comment: Interesting, yes, could you please paste the other code aswell? Will use this method for sure in future.

Comment: My bad, the code of the method PerformAction has been added.

Comment: Who cares about Min and Max, you only really want the average. And you'll see you have zeroes in there which is not very accurate (we as humans know it wasn't instantaneous) and thus skews your average as well. It's probably something to do with precision of the system clock. It's better to start the stop watch before the loop, stop it after and then take the average. All of this, of course, assuming you're running in release mode outside of the debugger and it's not all optimized away since the str variables don't get used for anything.

Comment: Why say NO to information? Min and Max can be usefull in some scenarios, maybe this one isn't one of them but my method is not specific and I use it for other purposes too. The user asked for an answer and I provided one, doesn't matter wheither its useless or not (Everybody knows that these kind of "optimisations" are useless).